# Can each module register its own handlers or must it be done from bootstrapper app?

Tags: mediatr

In a solution structure where there is one web api bootstrapper app that refences multiple modules projects, is it possible for each module to extend `IServiceCollection` and within it do something like:

In ModuleA:
`services.AddMediatR(ModuleAAssembly);`

In ModuleB:
`services.AddMediatR(ModuleBAssembly);`

All i can find is the usage in top level bootstrapper project startup file like:
`services.AddMediatR(ModuleAAssembly, ModuleBAssembly);`

It's not the end of the world, but it would be nicer if each module could register its own handlers.

My concern is that multiple calls to `AddMediatr` (even with different arguments) might mess up something since it's not documented.

Any ideas how to do it?